# How to Display this kind of data into UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am having NSArray in which it is having following data, i am using AFHTTPRequestOperation which give me result and after that i am doing
[ListOfName addObject:[responseData valueForKey:name]]; and getting following result and that result i want to display in tableview but can understand how to do it becuause i an new to iphone

```
(
        (
        "Richard Conover",
        "Richard Conover",
        "Kaitlyn Matheson",
        "Andrea Wannemaker",
        "Andrea Wannemaker",
        test,
        james,
        test,
        gaurav,
        sdfsdfs
    )
)
```

if i do NSArray.count it will return only 1 so how to print it separately in tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is set the `TableView` datasource to be the first object in that `Array` (which is another `Array`).  Something like this:

```
NSArray *myTableViewDataSourceArray = [myOriginalArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then use `myTableViewDataSourceArray` for the datasource methods of the `TableView`.

Comment: @EIJay thank you so much this is nice explanation and learn lot from you and i have seen your profile of stack overflow . Motivate me to not to bound with specific language thank u

Answer (score 1):

As per your structure, you having array with objects which also array.

That means,`[ListOfName addObject:[responseData valueForKey:name]];` will add array object. You try to load this array of data into your table view. So you can try this in your `tableViewDataSource`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView
{
return [[ListOfName objectAtIndex:0] count];
}
```

Comment: Nice Explanation and learn lot from you mani thank you for replay

Answer (score 1):

It's a **Nested Array** (means Array inside Array).

Howmany Nested Arrays you have ?

If it's 1 then you can use :

```
NSArray *finalArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

then you can use **finalArray** to populate the `UITableView`.

Comment: Unless you plan on altering the array after you instantiate it, more efficient to use an `NSArray` vs `NSMutableArray`.  Not really a big deal, but efficiency is nice :)